# Play 2.5 preserve context in async calls

Tags: scala, playframework, scalatest, playframework-2.5

In our controller class we reach out to another service to get some data :

```
Future<JsonNode> futureSite = someClient.getSite(siteId, queryParams);

return FutureConverters.toJava(futureSite).thenApplyAsync((siteJson) -> {
    Site site = Json.fromJson(siteJson, Site.class);
    try {
        return function.apply(site);
    } catch (RequestException e) {
        return e.result;
    }
}).exceptionally(throwable -> {
    if(throwable instanceof OurClientException) {
        if(((OurClientException) throwable).httpStatusCode == 404) {
           return entityNotFound("Site", siteId);
        }
    }
    return null;
});
```

What we notice is that context which is set in unit tests (we use scalatest-play) is lost and becomes null after we make the Async call `(FutureConverters.toJava(futureSite).thenApplyAsync((siteJson)`, as t is on a separate thread.

Which causes problem down in the controller code, where we use the above function ... request() would now throw a runtime exception saying there is no context available.

How can we preserve the context ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should inject play.libs.concurrent.HttpExecutionContext to your controller and then specify current context as second argument for CompletionStage#thenApplyAsync(..,..).

```
public class Application extends Controller {
@Inject HttpExecutionContext ec;

public CompletionStage<Result> index() {
    someCompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> { 
      // do something with request()
    }, ec.current());
}}
```

P.S. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaAsync#Using-CompletionStage-inside-an-Action

Answer (score 0):

I addition to **Nick's V** answer.

If you are building a non-blocking app using Play Java API, it might become quite cumbersome to inject `HttpExecutionContext` and pass `ec.current())` every time you need to call methods on `CompletionStage`.

To make life easier you can use a decorator, which will preserve the context between calls.

```
public class ContextPreservingCompletionStage<T> implements CompletionStage<T> {

    private HttpExecutionContext context;
    private CompletionStage<T> delegate;

    public ContextPreservingCompletionStage(CompletionStage<T> delegate,
                                            HttpExecutionContext context) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
        this.context = context;
    }
    ...
}
```

So you will need to pass context only once:

```
return new ContextPreservingCompletionStage<>(someCompletableFuture, context)
                                    .thenCompose(something -> {...});
                                    .thenApply(something -> {...});
```

Instead of

```
return someCompletableFuture.thenComposeAsync(something -> {...}, context.current())
                                .thenApplyAsync(something -> {...}, context.current());
```

That is particularly useful if you are building a multi-tier app, and passing `CompletionStage`s between different classes.

Full decorator implementation example [is here](https://gist.github.com/yury-kislaik/f143adb78516b9c97f4808e4305953e3).